# Creating a Ruby-like `binding.pry` macro in Clojure

Tags: clojure

I've been struggling to create a macro that'll allow me to dynamically bind whatever is in the `&env` into a `binding` form and then delegate to a `pry` like function to open a REPL that can see those bound `&env` symbols.

My simplistic `pry` func, which works as expected

```clj
(defn pry []
  (print (str "pry(" *ns* ")> "))
  (flush)
  (let [expr (read)]
    (when-not (= expr :exit)
      (println (eval expr))
      (recur))))
```

Using the `pry` func:

```
clojure-noob.core=> (def a 1)
#'clojure-noob.core/a
clojure-noob.core=> (pry)
pry(clojure-noob.core)> (+ a 1)
2
pry(clojure-noob.core)> :exit
nil
clojure-noob.core=>
```

My attempt at creating a dynamic invocation of `binding`:

```clj
(defmacro binding-pry []
  (let [ks (keys &env)]
    `(let [ks# '~ks
           vs# [~@ks]
           bs# (vec (interleave ks# vs#))]
       (binding bs# (pry)))))
```

However, this fails because the inner symbol `bs#` is not expanded to an actual vector but instead is the generated symbol and `binding` tosses a `clojure.core/binding requires a vector for its binding` exception.

```
clojure-noob.core=> (let [a 1 b 2] (binding-pry))
Syntax error macroexpanding clojure.core/binding at (/tmp/form-init14332359378145135257.clj:1:16).
clojure.core/binding requires a vector for its binding in clojure-noob.core:

clojure-noob.core=>
```

The code quoted form with a debug print, the `bs#` symbol is resolved when printing but I don't know how to make it resolve to a vector when constructing the `binding` form.

```
(defmacro binding-pry []
  (let [ks (keys &env)]
    `(let [ks# '~ks
           vs# [~@ks]
           bs# (vec (interleave ks# vs#))]
       (println bs#)
       `(binding bs# (pry)))))

clojure-noob.core=> (let [a 1 b 2] (binding-pry))
[a 1 b 2]
(clojure.core/binding clojure-noob.core/bs__2464__auto__ (clojure-noob.core/pry))
clojure-noob.core=>
```

I'm very confident I'm tackling this incorrectly but I don't see another approach.

Comment: That might be the best first question I've ever seen a new user post.

Comment: You are asking for "Ruby-like" behavior, but this is a Clojure question and not everyone will be familiar enough with Ruby to know what behavior you are expecting.  You have an example of your "simplistic" `pry` function, but as you say that's working as expected.  However, I don't see an example of what you expect from `binding-pry`.  If you add the expected behavior, it would be easier to help.

Answer (score 3):

[The Joy of Clojure](https://www.manning.com/books/the-joy-of-clojure-second-edition) demonstrates a `break` macro that does this already. I can't reproduce its source here, because it's EPL and not CC. But you can see its source at https://github.com/joyofclojure/book-source/blob/b76ef15/first-edition/src/joy/breakpoint.clj. It refers to a `contextual-eval` function as well: https://github.com/joyofclojure/book-source/blob/b76ef15/first-edition/src/joy/macros.clj#L4-L7.

Comment: One problem with this `contextual-eval` (and `break` which depends on it) is that it assumes that the values of the bindings in the environment "can be embedded in code", which is not true for various objects. For example, it will not work if there is a `Delay` in the environment. A correct implementation of `eval`-in-context can be found in the `plumatic/plumbing` library as [`eval-bound`](https://github.com/plumatic/plumbing/blob/master/src/plumbing/graph/positional.clj#L55L59).

Answer (score 1):

A first step towards improving your attempt could be writing:

```clj
(defmacro binding-pry []
  (let [ks (keys &env)]
    `(binding [~@(interleave ks ks)] (pry))))
```

This still doesn't work because `binding` expects that the symbols can be resolved to existing dynamic vars. To tackle this problem you could make `binding-pry` introduce such vars as shown below:

```clj
(defmacro binding-pry []
  (let [ks (keys &env)]
    `(do
       ~@(map (fn [k] `(def ~(with-meta k {:dynamic true}))) ks)
       (binding [~@(interleave ks ks)] (pry)))))
```

But this can have undesirable side-effects, like polluting the namespace with new var-names or making existing vars dynamic. So I would prefer an approach like the one mentioned in amalloy's answer but with a better implementation of `eval`-in-context (see my comment there).

To write a self-contained answer based on your `pry` function, let's first define `eval-in` which evaluates a form in an environment:

```clj
(defn eval-in [env form]
  (apply
    (eval `(fn* [~@(keys env)] ~form))
    (vals env)))
```

Then let's modify `pry` to take an environment as an argument and use `eval-in` instead of eval:

```clj
(defn pry [env]
  (let [prompt (str "pry(" *ns* ")> ")]
    (loop []
      (print prompt)
      (flush)
      (let [expr (read)]
        (when-not (= expr :exit)
          (println (eval-in env expr))
          (recur))))))
```

An equivalent, less primitive version could be:

```clj
(defn pry [env]
  (->> (repeatedly (let [prompt (str "pry(" *ns* ")> ")]
                     #(do (print prompt) (flush) (read))))
       (take-while (partial not= :exit))
       (run! (comp println (partial eval-in env)))))
```

Now we can define `binding-pry` as follows:

```clj
(defmacro binding-pry []
  `(pry ~(into {}
           (map (juxt (partial list 'quote) identity))
           (keys &env))))
```

Finally, here is a direct/"spaghetti" implementation of `binding-pry`:

```clj
(defmacro binding-pry []
  (let [ks (keys &env)]
    `(->> (repeatedly (let* [prompt# (str "pry(" *ns* ")> ")]
                        #(do (print prompt#) (flush) (read))))
          (take-while (partial not= :exit))
          (run! (comp println
                      #((eval `(fn* [~~@(map (partial list 'quote) ks)] ~%))
                        ~@ks))))))
```

Comment: Definitely an improvement on the function I linked to. You seem a bit enamored of point-free gymnastics, though - something like `(for [k (keys &env)] ['~k ~k])` is substantially simpler than the point-free juxt/map version.

Comment: @amalloy You mean `(for [k (keys &env)] [\`'~k ~k])` (notice the `\``). But this introduces an extra sequence (really minor drawback), so we could write the transducer as `(map (fn [k] [\`'~k k]))` instead. And yes, I love point-free in general (on a suitable basis, not just for the sake of it) because it facilitates algebraic treatment but I admit that in Clojure it usually feels cumbersome, especially in macros where the "point-full" syntax-quote idiom looks much clearer.

Comment: Right. I can just never remember how to write a backtick in SO comments, which makes commenting about macros tricky. I worry 0% about the cost of introducing an extra sequence *at compile time*, making a focus on readability even more reasonable.